# How can I get the combined matrix of all CSS transforms of an element?

Tags: javascript, css, html

Using Javascript, I need to get the transformation matrix of an element. It might not have any transformations, but its parents might. How can I get the combined value that maps the screen coordinate space to the element's coordinate space?

```
<div style="transform:scale(3.0)">
    <div style="transform:scale(0.5)">
        <h1 id="fubar">What is my scale?</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
     var a = document.querySelector("#fubar");

     // chrome: displays "none".
     // firefox: displays "matrix(1.5, 0, 0, 1.5, 0, 0)"
     // I need to get the firefox value in all browsers
     alert(window.getComputedStyle(a).transform);
</script>
```

Comment: I'm getting `none` both on Chrome 60 and Firefox 55.

Answer (score 2):

Calling `getCombinedMatrix(element)` will give you the combined matrix as an array.

```
function getCombinedMatrix(element) {
    var matrix = getMatrixOfElement(element);
    var node = element.parentNode;

    while(node && node instanceof Element) { // traverse dom tree
        var node_matrix = getMatrixOfElement(node);
        prependMatrix(matrix,node_matrix); // prepend matrix of parent node

        node = node.parentNode;
    }

    return matrix;
}

function getMatrixOfElement(element) {
    var matrix = [1,0,0,1,0,0]; // default matrix (no transforms)
    var raw_transform = window.getComputedStyle(element).transform;

    if (raw_transform && raw_transform !== 'none') {
                // remove string wrapper 'matrix(' and split into parts    
        var parts = raw_transform.slice(7,-1).split(','); 
        for(var i=0;i<parts.length;i++) {
            matrix[i] = parseFloat(parts[i]); // put string parts into matrix as float
        }
    }

    return matrix;
}

function prependMatrix(m1,m2) {
    // matrix multiplication
    var a1 = m1[0];
    var c1 = m1[2];
    var tx1 = m1[4];

    m1[0] = m2[0]*a1+m2[2]*m1[1];
    m1[1] = m2[1]*a1+m2[3]*m1[1];
    m1[2] = m2[0]*c1+m2[2]*m1[3];
    m1[3] = m2[1]*c1+m2[3]*m1[3];
    m1[4] = m2[0]*tx1+m2[2]*m1[5]+m2[4];
    m1[5] = m2[1]*tx1+m2[3]*m1[5]+m2[5];
}
```

**NOTE:** This does not take the transformOrigin into account, so rotations might cause wrong results.

Comment: This is good enough to start with. To get the complete transformation, you need to take into account both the element's offset and computed transformOrigin, and those of its parents.

Comment: @SteveHanov Aaah, that's why rotation transforms are not exactly correct. You got any hints on how to do that? I suppose you have to modify the prependMatrix in some way?

Answer (score 0):

Well.. it seems this is not supported in Chrome (it returns a proper matrix but couldn't find the values meaningful) but for Safari i guess you may do as follows;

```
var style = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("fubar")),
   matrix = new WebKitCSSMatrix(style.webkitTransform);
console.log(matrix.toString());
```

or you can access matrix properties individually as explained [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkitjs/webkitcssmatrix).

On the other hand for Chrome and Node there seems to exist a polyfill called [XCSSMatrix](https://github.com/jfsiii/XCSSMatrix)